# Search and match in Txt file (Java)

Tags: java, search, matching

Hi guys please is there anyone can help me out with this program?

write a program that asks the user to enter a postcode and returns the city for that
postcode. If the postcode in not in the list then it should return city not found.
The find city code must be in a separate method findCity()
The user should be able to continue entering postcodes until they enter 9999 to indicate they
are complete (9999 should not appear as “city not found”)

================================================
in the txt file:

Dandenong 3175
Frankstone 3199
Berwick 3816
Cranbourne 3977
Rosebud 3939

---

Thats what i've done so far.

```
import java.io.File;
```

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            File f = new File("Files\\cities.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
            String text;
            while(input.hasNextLine())
            {
                text = input.nextLine();
                process(text);
            }


        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }   
    }

    public static void process(String text)
    {   String name = null;
    int id;
        Scanner code = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the postcode");       
        id = code.nextInt();
        Scanner data = new Scanner(text);

         if(code.equals(0))System.out.println(name);

        name = data.next();
        id = data.nextInt();

        while(data.hasNextDouble())
        {

        }
    System.out.println(name+ " ");
//  System.out.println(id+ " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: what help do you need? where are you stuck? the code seems incomplete

Comment: you use the same variable (`id`) to get user input and then to get scanner data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        File f = new File("d:\\cities.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
        Map<Integer,String> cityCode = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

        String text;
        while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
            text = input.nextLine();
            Scanner data = new Scanner(text);
            String name = data.next();
            int id2 = data.nextInt();
            cityCode.put(id2, name);
        }
        System.out.println("enter the postcode");    
        Scanner code = new Scanner(System.in);
        int id = code.nextInt();
        if(cityCode.containsKey(id)) {
            System.out.println(cityCode.get(id));
        } else {
            System.out.println("City Not found");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straight forward approach:

First, you want user to enter a passcode. If `passcode` is lesser than 9999, you want to search the text file to find a city with that passcode. This thing can be implemented as:

```
        int passcode = 5; // Suppose passcode is 5. You may suppose any value lesser than 9999
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Ask user to  enter a passcode. If user enters 9999 the while loop is exited
        while(passcode < 9999)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter passcode: ");
            passcode = input.nextInt();
            // donot search if passcode is greater than or equal to 9999
            if(passcode < 9999)
              searchCity(passcode);
        }
```

`searchCity()` method works like:

```
public static String searchCity(int passcode) {
    Scanner citiesScanner = new Scanner(new File("Files\\cities.txt"));
    while(citiesScanner.hasNext()) {
      String city = citiesScanner.next();
      String pass = citiesScanner.next();
      if(Integer.parseInt(pass) == passcode) {
        return city;
      }
    }
    return "City not found";
}
```

Just try to break your problem into sub problems. Do some paper work before starting typing code. Things become a lot simpler this way.

Comment: Thanks very much, and yeah i need to work on that because I don't do paper work before I start.